Latent vectors that correspond to race and gender in StyleGAN3
As a part of my research, I need to produce 4 sets of fictitious profile image that are identical in all features of the image, except race and gender (White male, White female, Black male, Black female).
To do so, I'm planning to use pre-trained StyleGAN3. I know that I can fix the seed, and change the latent vectors that would slowly transform the image. However, I'm not too sure how I can change the latent vector such that I would only change race/gender of the image, and have everything else as constant as possible.
Is there a way to identify this, or should I use other GAN methods for this task?
